# How to redirect with a JWT authentication?

Tags: kotlin, authentication, server, jwt, ktor

I'm building a Kotlin web server with KTor and FreeMarker. I'm using the JWT Auth plugin to allow restrain the access of certain web pages to my users. I coded this signin route that is called by a form on a HTML page:

```
fun Route.signIn(
    hashingService: HashingService,
    tokenService: TokenService,
    tokenConfig: TokenConfig
) {
    post("signin") {
        val formData = call.receiveParameters()
        val username = formData["username"]
        val password = formData["password"]

        // for testing purposes I hardcoded my credentials right here, 
        // I will move them somewhere else when the code will work
        val correctUsername = "fredy"
        val correctPass = "8A2F42EE20F839F2A17D954E249AFF1E73E770682A4CE9D153EC42554F1DFBCA".lowercase()
        val userId = "user_id_test"
        val salt = "salt_test"

        val user = if(username == correctUsername) username else null

        if(user == null) {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Incorrect username or password")
            return@post
        }

        val isValidPassword = hashingService.verify(
            value = password!!,
            saltedHash = SaltedHash(
                hash = correctPass,
                salt = salt
            )
        )
        if(!isValidPassword) {
            println("Entered hash: ${DigestUtils.sha256Hex("${salt}${password}")}, Hashed PW: $correctPass")
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Incorrect username or password")
            return@post
        }

        val token = tokenService.generate(
            config = tokenConfig,
            TokenClaim(
                name = "userId",
                value = userId
            )
        )
        
        // I want to redirect the authenticated user to the "songs" page
        call.respondRedirect{
            it.apply {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTP
                host = "127.0.0.1"
                path("songs")
                parameters.append("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have secured this route with the authenticate keyword :

```
fun Route.webPages() {
    authenticate {
        get("songs") {
            call.respond(
                FreeMarkerContent( "songPage.ftl", null)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to redirect the signed in user to the "songs" page but I still can't acces it. Instead I have this error :

```
Matched routes:
  "" -> "(authenticate "default")" -> "songs" -> "(method:GET)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /(authenticate "default")/songs/(method:GET)
2023-04-15 21:04:31.226 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication - Trying to authenticate /songs?Authorization=Bearer+eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ1c2VycyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly8wLjAuMC4wOjgwODAiLCJleHAiOjE3MTMxNDMwNzEsInVzZXJJZCI6ImFhYSJ9.9rGMGJci3BwyKmq6Kng_BIz-DqEnHJbAJDs32uwj7xQ with null
2023-04-15 21:04:31.226 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.auth.Authentication - Authentication failed for /songs?Authorization=Bearer+eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ1c2VycyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly8wLjAuMC4wOjgwODAiLCJleHAiOjE3MTMxNDMwNzEsInVzZXJJZCI6ImFhYSJ9.9rGMGJci3BwyKmq6Kng_BIz-DqEnHJbAJDs32uwj7xQ with provider io.ktor.server.auth.jwt.JWTAuthenticationProvider@69641455
2023-04-15 21:04:31.226 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - Skipping because body is already converted.
2023-04-15 21:04:31.227 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] INFO  Application - 401 Unauthorized: GET - /songs in 1ms
```

I think the problem is the methhod to send the token in the response. The JWTProvider is not catching my Token but I don't know how to send it correctly.
Does someone have an idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: I also tried these lines without success :  call.response.headers.append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, "Bearer $token")
call.respondRedirect("/songs")

Comment: I also tried to make the redirection client side. The server "/signin" respond with a HttpStatus.OK and a message that provide the JWT. When received, the client use this token to fetch a web page. But I'm only able to use fetch() function, I can't render the page. I don't know what to do now ...

Comment: The server expects the `Authorization` **header**, but you can't set it when redirecting a client. Also, you have to use Javascript to send the header because sending it through an HTML form is impossible too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! How can I send a get request with a Auth header using javascript to open a new page ?

Comment: What do you mean by opening a new page?

Comment: I have pages that I want only authenticatd users can acces. For example : once a user is authenticated he can browse the songs page